# Assign a variable outside a string function in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am struggling for a while to assign the value returned by this function to a variable outside of it, in viewDidLoad but is returning an empty string. 
getUid() - is returning the firebase uid
prRef - is calling the firebase table for users

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

```
var currentWorkplaceId: String?

func getCurrentWorkplaceId() -> String {

    //completion:@escaping (Bool)->Void
    var workplaceid = String()
    prRef.child(getUid())
        .child("workplace_id")
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            workplaceid = snapshot.value as! String
    })
    return workplaceid
}
```

usage:

```
currentWorkplaceId = getCurrentWorkplaceId()
```

Comment: Its a mixture of synchronous (getCurrentWorkpaceId() is synchronous) and asynchronous, (observesingleevent is asynchronous). You can't mix them up like that.  It is not working because the return statement is being executed *before* the closure is assigning the value to workplaceid. Change getCurrentWorkplaceId() to pass the value of workplaceid to the caller via a closure, in the same way observeSingleEvent is passing its value to getCurrentWorkplaceId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observeSingleEvent` is probably asynchronous with a callback.  So at the time you call return, `workplaceid` hasn't been assigned yet.  You need to do the same with your own callback.

```
func getCurrentWorkplaceId(_ completion: @escaping (_ workplaceId: String)->()) {

    //completion:@escaping (Bool)->Void
    prRef.child(getUid())
    .child("workplace_id")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        completion(snapshot.value as! String)
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
getCurrentWorkplaceId() { workplaceId in
    self.currentWorkplaceId = workplaceId
}
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot Frankie! It worked like a charm.